# Mac's analogue to Windows' Application Desktop Toolbars API (appbar)

Tags: c++, macos, qt, appbar

In Window there is so called [appbar API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for creation of custom desktop panels.
These panels behave very similar to taskbar: they always occupy some screen space and cannot be overlapped by other windows.

I'm looking for similar API in OS X.

Specifically I'm writing using Qt + C++ on Mac 10.7.5, but any suggestions are welcome.